# Android load data from SQLite Database into next activity

Tags: android, listview

I have a listView which loads data from SQLite database and right now I would want to implement an onclicklistener to the list. When users click on the list, it should bring them to the next activity and load the corresponding data into TextView. My question is how would I pass the data of the list for example it is a list of "Topics" and user click on the topic "My Home". I want to pass the topic "My Home" to the next activity so that I know which corresponding data to be retrieved respectively.

How do I go about it? Do I "putExtras" to the new Intent? or there is another way. Below are part of my codes which display the listview:

```
ListView listContent = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contentlist);
        mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
        mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();

        Cursor cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        String[] from = new String[] { SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text };

        SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listrow, cursor, from, to);

        listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

        mySQLiteAdapter.close();

        //Onclick ListView setlistener
        listContent.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        listContent.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Intent summaryIntent = new Intent(DocumentListActivity.this, ViewDocumentActivity.class);
//              summaryIntent.putExtra("SummTopic", value);
            }
        });
```

EDITED:
This part is on the next activity.

```
Intent i = getIntent();
        extraTopic = i.getStringExtra("SummTopic");

        mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        Cursor allrows  = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+  TABLE + " WHERE topic = \" " + extraTopic + " \" " , null);

        Integer cindex = allrows.getColumnIndex("topic");
        Integer cindex1 = allrows.getColumnIndex("text1");
        Integer cindex2 = allrows.getColumnIndex("text2");
```

I got an error while retrieving from database:

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0
```

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Intent summaryIntent = new Intent(DocumentListActivity.this, ViewDocumentActivity.class);
            Cursor c = (Cursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            summaryIntent.putExtra("SummTopic", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT)));
            startActivity(summaryIntent);
        }
```

or you can pass `id` (`summaryIntent.putExtra("SummTopicId", id);`) of this row and "ask db" in next Activity for Topic with this id

EDIT:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    Intent i = getIntent(); 
    String extraTopic = i.getStringExtra("SummTopic"); 
    //or long extraTopic = i.getLongExtra("SummTopic"); if you put id there (which is better)
        mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    String[] args = new String[] { extraTopic };
    //or String[] args = new String[] { Long.toString(extraTopic) }; with id version
        Cursor singleRow  = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+  TABLE + " WHERE topic=?" , args);
    //args is better then escaping special chars in query
    //and it should be single row so we've changed var name :)
    if(singleRow.moveToFirst()){ //we should do moveToFirst before we can use Cursor
        Integer cindex = allrows.getColumnIndex("topic");
        Integer cindex1 = allrows.getColumnIndex("text1");
        Integer cindex2 = allrows.getColumnIndex("text2");
        //setup views and stuff ....
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Oops we did not find topic, detail activity was closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this does helps. thanks. but i have an error while retrieving on the next activity. Could you help to refer my codes above in the edited part. thanks

Comment: Dear Selvin, I have another question, when I press the back button to go back to the ListView which loads data from database, I couldn't get the list. Any idea how to reload that ListView from db again? is it to use notifyDataSetChanged();? Is there an example to this? thanks.

Comment: i don't know the easy way ... on your place i will go for ContentProvider and CursorLoader ...but it's a lot of work to do ... maybe you sould ask new question and someone will help you

Comment: hmmm just quick try in Activity with list made cursorAdapter a field than on onResume add `super.onResume(); cursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Intent for this.

```
Intent intent= new Intent(context,classname.class);
intent.putExtra("name",string);
```

You can get it in the target class name using `intent.getextra()`.

Answer (score 0):

After you have used `setContentView(...)` you need to reference your String and get the text such as...

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text);
String theText = et.getText().toString();
```

To pass it to another Activity you use an Intent. Example...

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyNewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("text_label", theText);
startActivity(i);
```

In the new Activity (`in onCreate()`), you get the Intent and retrieve the String...

```
public class MyNewActivity extends Activity {

    String uriString;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(...) {

        ...

        Intent i = getIntent();
        uriString = i.getStringExtra("text_label");

    }
}
```

**EDITED :**

to get String From Listview you can apply below code and get ITEM String and Pass it to Next Activity:

```
 listContent.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
    String ITEM=listContent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                //Intent summaryIntent = new Intent(DocumentListActivity.this, // ViewDocumentActivity.class);
//              summaryIntent.putExtra("SummTopic", value);
            }
        });
```

Comment: how do I get the text from the ListView? Maybe I didnt emphasize properly. I want to get the "Topic" which is part of the ListView.

Comment: Edited My Answer. go through it.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are using an adapter to fill your list with some data. So you need to override getItem(int position) method in your adapter:

```
 @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
       //Note that return type should be the same you you use to initilise items oof the adapter. E.g. String or some custom Topic class
       Object someObject = mObjects[position];

       return someObject;    
    }
```

Then you need to set an item click listener to you list

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Object someObject = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);

                Intent i = new Intent(this, MyNewActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("text_label", someObject.toString());
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```